# What is the most common way to program ATmega328? Through SPI or USART or others?

Tags: atmega

I am learning ATmega328 and plan to design it into my custom circuit. I need to know how I should set up to loan programs into the ATmega328 so I can set up the hardware to do that. Is it through SPI or USART or some other ways.

Also, I am studying the datasheet of ATmega328, I studied SPI, unless I should us USART, I don't want to waste my time studying that.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "the most common way" as the chip itself only supports only two methods natively, the high voltage parallel programming (HVPP) and in-system serial programming (ISP) which is a serial interface that is compatible with SPI.

It does not support UART or any other interface, not unless you use one of the two methods above to program a bootloader which supports programming the MCU over some other interface with some other protocol, for example UART.

Comment: Note that you can get the chips pre-loaded with a bootloader, but this is an extra step by (and extra cost to) the supplier.

Answer (score 0):

Personally when I always used to use them, I programmed them via the 6-pin ICSP *(in circuit serial programming)* header on the Arduino boards. This uses SPI (MISO/MOSI/SCK/RST) and works very well.

You can see the way it is connected by looking at the [reference schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf) but it's very simple.

To actually do the programming I used a *WaveShare* USB AVRISP XPii programmer: it's cheap, easy to use and does the job reliably.

At the risk of being shot down in flames though, are you *really* sure that you want to learn with the ATmega328? It was a competent little chip at the time but these days it's blown away by 32-bit alternatives like the RP2040 (*aka* Raspberry Pi Pico) that are a heck of a lot more capable and easier to use (just my opinion!)

Comment: Thanks for the reply MartinC. I looked at the datasheet of RP2040, it's a lot longer. I want something simple for small projects, That's way more than I ever imagine to use.

Comment: I chose ATmega328 because I bought an Elegoo kit from Amazon, it's a 28pin dip, easy to solder than the surface mount with very small pins and a lot of pins. I just hope it does not get obsoleted any time soon. I have not been designing MPU circuits for a long time, I just want to keep up with the newer MPU. Last time I really design I used HC11, before that, 8085. There goes to show. I am mainly analog RF engineer. Just do this as a hobby.

Comment: I definitely want a small MPU, this ATmega328 is a little too complicate to me already. My main concern is whether this ATmega328 will be around and not obsoleted any time soon. At my age(retired long time) I want to find one that last my life time so I can learn one and be done with. :))

Comment: Completely understood @Alan0354. There's nothing wrong with the ATmega328 and I imagine it'll be around for a while yet due to the large installed base of 'Arduino' users. Incidentally if you don't need all the capabilities of the '328 then another option you might look at is a PIC (e.g. https://mu.microchip.com/8-bit-microcontrollers-architecture-of-the-pic16)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. But I am close to 200pages into the datasheets already. Hoping I can do some assembly programming soon.

Comment: Just checking, but you do know that you can write code for the ATmega devices ('AVR') using the GNU C compiler? (e.g. see https://tinusaur.com/guides/avr-gcc-toolchain/)

Comment: For the whole process of programming the ATmega, including setting up all the tools, I can't recommend this book highly enough: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1449355781